# Pear / Pecl problem with prebuild script in Azure Webapp

Tags: php, azure-web-app-service, pear, pecl

When trying to use pecl in a prebuild or postbuild script with Azure webapps I get the following error:

```
/tmp/oryx/platforms/php/7.4.9/bin/pecl: 28: exec: /opt/php/7.4.9/bin/php: not found
```

The same script works in one of the following conditions:

- Calling it in a WebSSH shell with php version set to 7.4
- Calling it in a prebuild with php version set to 7.3

I also tried to set php_bin, or php_dir using commandline arguments when calling pecl. Without success.

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

php --version
pecl config-show
```

It might be related to the removal of pear, as stated here:
https://github.com/php/php-src/pull/3781

I am however a bit confused, that it works when I login via webssh.

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at the pecl source, I figured out a workaround:
Setting the following enviroment variables:

- PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=php
- PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/oryx/platforms/php/7.4.9/lib/php

Full command:

```
PHP_PEAR_PHP_BIN=php PHP_PEAR_INSTALL_DIR=/tmp/oryx/platforms/php/7.4.9/lib/php pecl config-show
```